# Fix a navigation bar to top once it's been scrolled down to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my navigation bar to get fixed to the top only once it's been reached, not by default (like class="navbar-fixed-top"). Bootstrap affix is not working for me, so I decided to find a JQuery solition.
[Demo of what I want](http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/df8tb)

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-wrapper"><!--nav-wrapper-->
        <div class="container"><!--container-->
            <div class="row" id="navigation"><!--header-->
                <div class="col-md-12"><!--col-md-12-->
                    <div class="nav"><!--nav-->
                        <div class="#">
                         <ul id="#">
                            <li id="#" class="..."><a href="...">Home</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-6478" class="..."><a href="...">About EFTI</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-27" class="..."><a href="...">Our Coaches</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-6469" class="..."><a href="...">Blog</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-6568" class="..."><a href="...">EFTI Forum</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-6477" class="..."><a href="...">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul></div>                </div><!--nav-->
                 </div><!--col-md-12-->
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div><!--header-->
        </div><!--container-->
    </div>
```

Would code similar to this do the job:

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function(){ 
var div_pos_from_top = $('#nav').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop(); 

if (div_pos_from_top < 300) { 
$('#nav').css('... , ...'); 
} else { 
$('#nav').css('... , ....'); 
} 
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but may the solution be to actually just set the navbar's css "position" property to fixed? (once you scrolled to the desired point)

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: I don't know how to put it in the loop, to be honest. Would $(#nav).css('position', 'fixed') work?

Comment: Yes, it actually does. Not sure how to make it to go back to relative, though. The basic idea is that by putting it to position: fixed it will stick wherever you want, but you also should set margins everytime... Maybe there is a cleverer way to do that, though :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most efficient loop either. Put the var outside so we get the position when the document loads. But this is the best way I found to do it, at least if you're going to write something yourself. Hope that helps!

Your code has `nav` as a class, it needs to be set as an id.

```js
var position = $("#nav").offset().top;

function stickyHeader() {
  if (position < $(document).scrollTop()) {
    $("#nav").addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    $("#nav").removeClass("sticky");
  }
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  stickyHeader();
});
```

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-wrapper">
  <!--nav-wrapper-->
  <div class="container">
    <!--container-->
    <div class="row" id="navigation">
      <!--header-->
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <!--col-md-12-->
        <div id="nav">
          <!--nav-->
          <div class="#">
            <ul id="#">
              <li id="#" class="..."><a href="...">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-6478" class="..."><a href="...">About EFTI</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-27" class="..."><a href="...">Our Coaches</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-6469" class="..."><a href="...">Blog</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-6568" class="..."><a href="...">EFTI Forum</a>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-item-6477" class="..."><a href="...">Contact Us</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--nav-->
      </div>
      <!--col-md-12-->
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <!--header-->

    <body>
      <h1>Scrolling Sticky Header</h1>

      <div class="content">
        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
          quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
          qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
          quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
          qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
        <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
          quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
          eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit
          qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </div>
  <!--container-->
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my code. But yeah you're attempting to bind the the nav class, then call the nav id?

Comment: Binding it to the nav-wrapper is the only one that works. Your function does a good job however. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The idea looks good. What I used in the past is

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  if(scroll > 100) {
    $('#nav').addClass('fix');
  } else {
    $('#nav').removeClass('fix');
  }
});
```

Maybe the loop isn't the most efficient, but it works.

Comment: Could you please edit your post to show me how the whole thing should look like? Is $(#nav).css('position','fixed') the right syntax?